# grails redirect after successful login

Tags: grails, redirect, spring-security, multi-tenant

I'm currently building a web shop (which is supposed to support multi tenancy).

So my approach is to have a url setup like

appName/shops/shop1/controller/action
appName/shops/shop2/controller/action

Depending on the shop (shop1 or shop2) I have a different assortment. Then I have a list with items and a button to add them to the shopping cart. This action is secured an only accessible for logged in users.

My Problem is the following:
Default behaviour when clicking the "secured" button is to get redirected to appName/login/auth. This way I'm losing context of the shop that the user was browsing. I'm not sure if I can provide the context/shop to the auth process in a way that I can redirect to the respective shop after a successfull log in.

Another approach would be to provide a custom button instead that redirects to the login page if the user is not logged in which provides the context/shop name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following scheme for the urls instead:
**shop1.appName/controller/action**, **shop2.appName/controller/action**. The login urls for each of the subdomains (shop1, shop2) will be: shop1.appName/login/auth, shop2.appName/login/auth. This way the context will never be lost. In case, you want the logged in user also is able to access appname/otherController/action as well (without logging in again), you may need to do something like this: http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2012/03/21/sharing-http-session-between-subdomains/

Comment: Thank you fou your reply. That's a good idea which could work I think. Nonetheless I followed a different approach which works fine. :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953410/springsecurity-grails-how-to-change-loginformurl-in-loginurlauthenticationentryp/25035958#25035958